# Are Noachides prohibited from Slander (Lashon Hara)?

Tags: noachide-laws, lashon-hara-slander

The Jerusalem Talmud in Peah 1:1 says,

> ארבעה דברים שהן נפרעין מן האדם בעולם הזה והקרן קיימת לו לעולם הבא
> ואילו הן עבודה זרה וגילוי עריות ושפיכות דמים ולשון הרע כנגד כולן
>
> There are four things that a person has to pay for in this world and
> the principal remains for him in the World to Come: idolatry,
> abominable physical relationships, and murder, but slander (lashon
> hara) is equivalent to all of these.

Based on this, Noachides, who are commanded against idolatry, abominable physical relationships, and murder should even more so have a commandment against slander. If so, why isn’t slander mentioned as one of the Noachide prohibitions? (Is it perhaps because a Noachide wouldn’t incur a death penalty for slander unlike the other 7, but slander is nevertheless still prohibited?)

Comment: Is your question why it isn’t part of the 7 mitvohs, or IF it’s part of the 7 mitzvohs?

Comment: > If so, why isn’t slander mentioned as one of the Noachide prohibitions?

The noachide laws are 7 categories of prohibitions, not being listed as a prohibition does not mean it is not prohibited

Comment: As per the חפץ חיים the prohibition of slander amongst ישראל only applies to fellow ישראל

Comment: In my understanding, those are educational statements, rather than factual. They aim to educate the audience, not to coherently explain a phenomenon. This is similar to Mishna in Shabbos "עַל שָׁלֹשׁ עֲבֵירוֹת נָשִׁים מֵתוֹת בִּשְׁעַת לֵידָתָן: עַל שֶׁאֵינָן זְהִירוֹת בַּנִּדָּה, בַּחַלָּה, וּבְהַדְלָקַת הַנֵּר." It does not try to make a causal correlation but rather edicate women to value those Mitzvos (unfortunately out of fear of death).

Comment: I guess it depends on what body of work you're studying. The Talmud makes distinctions like that. I'm finding that looking strictly at the Torah, it's hard to find a line between the groups. Leviticus 24:22
Ye shall have one manner of law, as well for the stranger as for the home-born; for I am the LORD your God.
מִשְׁפַּ֤ט אֶחָד֙ יִהְיֶ֣ה לָכֶ֔ם כַּגֵּ֥ר כָּאֶזְרָ֖ח יִהְיֶ֑ה כִּ֛י אֲנִ֥י יְהוָ֖ה אֱלֹהֵיכֶֽם׃

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Mevo_HaTalmud_(Chajes).19.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://www.wikinoah.org/en/index.php/Gossip_in_Noahide_Law) for a larger discussion:

- Rav Moshe Bogomilsky holds lashon hara does apply as it falls under murder based on the Gemara Bava Metziah (58b) that publicly embarrassing another is as if he spills his blood.
- Rabbi Nissan Dubov Justice holds it is part of their requirement to establish courts of justice to avoid damaging a person's reputation in public.
- Rabbi Yeshayahu HaKohen Hollander holds they are not required to avoid saying lashon hara; however, it would be wise for communal peace to accept it.

Comment: How could Rav Moshe Bogomilsky say that! As @zunior said, the Chafetz Chaim says that Lashon Hara is only Lashon Hara against Yidden. Basically implying that nonJews have no chiyuv to not speak Lashon Hara.